# Plot a ceteris paribus relationship between two variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a feeling this might be a duplicate, but I could not find a similar enough question.

I know that I can plot the relationship between two variables in `ggplot2` as below (Plotting). But when I plot this relationship, it does not take any other variables into account. My question now, is whether it is possible, to feed `ggplot2` for example the following model:

```
glm_mod <- glm(Count~empl + Dummy + Urbanisation_Dummy, family=quasipoisson, data=dat)
```

And then let `ggplot2` plot the ceteris paribus relationship between the two variables (`Continuous` and `empl`).

## Plotting

```
plot_list <- ggplot(dat, aes(x=Count, y=empl)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    geom_smooth(aes(colour="fit", fill="fit"), , 
                size = 2 ) + 
    geom_smooth(aes(colour="linear", fill="linear"), 
                method="lm", 
                formula=y ~ x, ) + 
    # facet_zoom(xlim = c(-10, 10), ylim=c(100000000, -100000000)) +
    scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set1") + 
    scale_colour_brewer(palette="Set1") + 
    theme_classic() + 
    labs(colour="Functional Form", fill="Functional Form")
plot_list
plot_list_build = ggplot_build(plot_list)
```

## DATA

```
dat <- structure(list(ordinal_dep_var = structure(c(4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", 
"1", "2", "3"), class = c("ordered", "factor")), Dummy = c(1, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), Count = c(41.6666666666667, 
46.1538461538462, 33.3333333333333, 15, 11.1111111111111, 7.5098814229249, 
0, 0, 25, 50, 0, 0, 21.4285714285714, 0, 26.6666666666667, 30.3030303030303, 
100, 44.6428571428571, 100, 100, 100, 30, 0, 40, 0, 41.8181818181818, 
50, 15.1515151515152, 15.3846153846154, 27.2727272727273, 41.6666666666667, 
20, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 50, 0, 25, 11.5384615384615, 0, 7.5, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 3.84615384615385, 14.2857142857143, 44.4444444444444, 0, 
1.84089414858646, 1.84089414858646, 1.84089414858646, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 40, 0, 0, 0, 33.3333333333333, 100, 50, 
100, 0, 0, 5, 47.3684210526316, 0, 0, 0, 44.4444444444444, 20, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 50, 100, 60, 0, 33.3333333333333, 10, 10, 42.8571428571429, 
0, 23.0769230769231, 100, 0, 100, 75, 0, 100, 20, 0, 0, 0, 25, 
5, 0, 40, 66.6666666666667, 33.3333333333333, 33.3333333333333, 
0, 0, 50, 50, 0, 75, 0, 50, 9.09090909090909, 14.2857142857143, 
50, 0, 0, 0, 20, 11.1111111111111, 100, 25, 22.2222222222222, 
0, 0, 0, 25, 66.6666666666667, 60, 100, 42.3076923076923, 25, 
0, 7.69230769230769, 0, 0), Dummy2 = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), format.stata = "%14.0f", class = c("haven_labelled", 
"vctrs_vctr", "double"), labels = c(Yes = 1, No = 2)), Urbanisation_Dummy = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("City > 250", 
"50k-250k", "< 50k"), class = "factor"), Size_Dummy = structure(c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Employees: < 10", 
"Employees: 10-19", "Employees: 20+"), class = "factor"), empl = structure(c(116, 
72, 74, 450, 24, 160, 11, 4, 35, 2, 10, 50, 45, 24, 136, 135, 
6, 64, 72, 56, 50, 46, 8, 8, 26, 100, 40, 20, 23, 45, 50, 7, 
6, 45, 10, 20, 8, 900, 12, 8, 10, 4, 2, 2, 630, 4, 6, 2, 26, 
20, 8, 1, 1, 0, 24, 12, 70, 43, 6, 20, 70, 87, 5, 11, 300, 7, 
5, 7, 40, 700, 70, 5, 200, 160, 12, 49, 3, 6, 5, 245, 21, 5, 
10, 22, 3, 20, 1930, 2, 5, 6, 30, 31, 7, 2, 2, 86, 26, 3, 28, 
6, 12, 2, 35, 5, 7, 80, 195, 9, 26, 90, 3, 26, 9, 140, 140, 7, 
11, 56, 10, 53, 258, 100, 9, 4, 10, 76, 26, 70, 200, 2480, 2, 
11, 10, 4, 2, 41, 180, 14, 39, 7, 2, 8, 150, 33), format.stata = "%9.0g")), row.names = c(NA, 
-144L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that in essence you are interested in plotting marginal effects? https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/margins/vignettes/Introduction.html

Comment: @Datapumpernickel Thanks you for your comment. A bit dumb of me, since I am actually already using that package. I think I misread what 'cplot' was actually doing. Nevertheless I would still be interested in doing it with ggplot if possible.

Comment: Added some ideas below. If your model is not too large, you could loop over the glm() function and simulate it a few thousand times to get nicer bootstrapped confidence intervals. Some very basic way of doing this manually with for loops is explained [here](https://rpubs.com/vadimus/bootstrap)

Comment: Ok. i made some edits below and a correction. Of course predictions have to be exponentiated. had forgotten that. Hopefully somebody else looks at this and flags any other errors. Besides, I added a way to also account for your other values.

Answer (score 1):

This is a barebone answer. You can make this much nices with the actual predict() functions, plotting confidence bands, etc.

But in essence you can extract the coefficients and then calculate by hand. It is possible that I am missing something here...

**EDIT**: Take into account, that this is ceteris paribus with certain decisions with the dummies! In this case, with Dummy == 1 and Urbainsation < 50k.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

preds <- data.frame()
for(value in dat$empl){
  predicted_value <- coef(glm_mod)[1] + 1*coef(glm_mod)[3] + 1*coef(glm_mod)[4] + value*coef(glm_mod)[2]
  preds <- bind_rows(preds, data.frame(Count = exp(predicted_value), empl = value))
}


ggplot2::ggplot(preds) + 
  ggplot2::geom_point(aes(x = empl, y = Count))

### with predict()
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

preds <- data.frame()
for(value in dat$empl){
  predicted_value <- predict(glm_mod, data.frame(empl = value, Dummy = 1, Urbanisation_Dummy = "< 50k"), type = "response")
  preds <- bind_rows(preds, data.frame(Count = predicted_value, empl = value))
}


ggplot2::ggplot(preds) + 
  ggplot2::geom_point(aes(x = empl, y = Count))

### over different values of dummies
preds <- data.frame()
for(value in dat$empl){
  for(dummy in c(0,1)){
    for(urbanisation in unique(dat$Urbanisation_Dummy)){
      predicted_value <- predict(glm_mod, data.frame(empl = value, Dummy = dummy, Urbanisation_Dummy = "< 50k"), type = "response")
      preds <- bind_rows(preds, data.frame(Count = predicted_value, empl = value, Dummy = dummy, urbanisation = urbanisation))
    }
  }
}


ggplot2::ggplot(preds) + 
  ggplot2::geom_point(aes(x = empl, y = Count, color = as.factor(Dummy), group = as.factor(Dummy)))+
  facet_grid(.~urbanisation)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great. With regard to your EDIT. I would in my example have a country variable in there (with around 50 countries). I guess it is not possible to account for these effects (even for an `lm` for example)?

Comment: I added another edit (sorry, this keeps on changing...) with a possibility to account for different values of dummies. Are the countries included in your glm-model? If so, then yes you can of course pass these values to the predict() function. How you would plot this depends a lot on what you want to show. What is your main variable? Do you want to show the difference between two countries or rather the marginal difference between urbanisation dummies?

Comment: No worries, I am super happy with your help. The countries are normally included in the model yes (But for control. I am in no way interested in there values). There are two relationships I am really interest in. The first one (first stage) is between `ordinal_dep_var` and `Dummy` (for which I will have to use a `polr`). The second (stage) would be between `Count` and `ordinal_dep_var` as an independent variable.

Comment: Sorry, this is getting really complicated. I just made an extremely simple example (because I did not realise it would be this complicated).

Comment: Ok. I think then I would look at the marginal plots for all the countries (loop over them like with urbanization above) and see if there is some strong differences. If not, I would make a plot with marginal effects for one country and use that as illustration of the effect... But I must say, I am out of my depth here... 
Also I  recommend adding the actual values to your plot, so that it becomes evident, that you have very little observations for high values of empl...

Comment: I can understand! Like I said, I though I was asking a simple question (and would get a simple answer, with which I could take it from there). Turns out it got really complicated really quickly. In any case, thank you very much for your help and your useful comments!